# Why can I modify a table that is referenced by a view with SCHEMABINDING?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Looking for some clarification on SCHEMABINDING. I read in a forum that if you create a view with Schemabinding, the base table cannot be altered.

So I created a view with SCHEMABINDING and was able to drop a column from the base table.

So, now I am confused on what is the purpose of SCHEMABINDING and when and where should this be used?

**NOTE**: I tried to drop the base table and I was not able to do so because of SCHEMABINDING.

Comment: Is this mysql or SQL Server? Different things. OH, and silly question maybe, but was the column you dropped included in the view?

Comment: ohhh yesss...that column is not in the view.

Comment: well, that's your answer, as Aaron explained in great detail below.

Answer (score 7):

`SCHEMABINDING` is not restricted to just object-level bindings. In this case, it is actually possible to only be bound to specific columns. Take this very trivial example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(a INT, b INT);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vFoo 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  SELECT a FROM dbo.foo;
GO
```

Since the view only references column `a`, I can drop `b` no problem:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo DROP COLUMN b;
GO
```

But as soon as I try to touch `a`, problem:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo DROP COLUMN a;
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   
> The object 'vFoo' is dependent on column 'a'.
>   
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 17
>   
> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN a failed because one or more objects access this column.

So, whoever wrote what they wrote in that forum, they weren't very explicit or elaborate. [The documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) is a little more helpful, but you still need to extrapolate:

> ... the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition.

Notice the sentence does not end after the word "modified." Dropping a column that isn't referenced in the view is not modifying the table in a way that would affect the view definition, because it does not know about a column it doesn't reference.